# Is there any limit to push message on same device

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hello I am working on a project where `GCM` is being used very much to notifify users for certain actions. For this sometimes in a 1 minutes server is continous pushing notification (3-4 messages) to same device.

But I noticed that I receive everytime only 1 message then other 2-3 messages are being discarded. I'm not sure if this is intentional to avoid spamming by Google ?

Does anyone have experience of it. Please share.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending the messages from your server with the same `collapse_key`, the GCM server will discard some of them if it receives a message with collapse_key X before it managed to send the last message having the same collapse_key.

If you don't use collapse key, GCM server will discard some of your messages if it accumulated over a 100 messages for the same device that haven't been sent yet.

You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#collapsible).

Comment: I'm not sure where we have to use `collapse_key.` ? what exactly it do ?

Comment: @Williams you should use collapse_key when you implement "Send-to-Sync" mechanism on your push server. This mechanism is described in a [GCM documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#collapsible) and you should not use 'collapse_key' if your clients should receive each push message (with payload). Also if you use 'collapse_key' GCM server enables "Throttling" mechanism which can add some delay time to push message delivery, be aware about it. Check please does your push server use 'collapse_key' parameter or not!?

Comment: @Samik thanks for your help. I am not using any `collapse_key` concept on server.